# Create Class from another class

Tags: javascript, class

I want to make a class that creates an element with a few properties added on to it.
So far this is what my code looks like:

```
function CreateItem(n,u) {
    this=document.createElement('li');
    this.classList.add('ui-state-default');
    this.setAttribute('value',u);
    this.innerHTML=n;
    }
```

It doesn't work. I keep getting an error:

```
ReferenceError
  arguments: Array[0]
  message: "_"
  stack: "_"
  type: "invalid_lhs_in_assignment"
  __proto__: Error
```

What I want is it to return an `li` element like this:

```
<li value="u">n</li>
```

If it helps here's what I'm using:

```
Google Chrome:  13.0.782.1 (Official Build 87465) dev
OS: Linux
WebKit: 535.1 (trunk@87771)
JavaScript: V8 3.4.0.1
Flash:  10.3 r181
User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.1 Safari/535.1
```

and debugging with Chrome Dev Tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to make a class that creates an
>   element with a few properties added on
>   to it. So far this is what my code
>   looks like:

Javascript doesn't have classes, what you are attempting to write is a function.

```
> function CreateItem(n,u) {
```

By convention, function names starting with a capital letter are constructors and should be called with *new*. You don't show how the function is called, but I expect it is with *new*.

```
>     this=document.createElement('li');
```

You can't assign a value to *this* (hence why the error message says `invalid_lhs_in_assignment`)), it is set when the execution context is entered and can't be changed.

```
>     this.classList.add('ui-state-default');
```

Even if you could assign to *this*, li elements don't have a *classList* method.

```
>     this.setAttribute('value',u);
```

There is rarely a good reason to use *setAttribute*, it is much better to just set the DOM property:

```
  el.value = u;
```

The function can be as suggested by Arend (more or less).

Comment: Ah, thanks for going in depth in the javascript dom - I'm a lazy guy who doesn't actually know the dom that much, but I know my way around the jQuery wrapper.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can't write to "this"
But this will work:

```
function CreateItem(n,u) {
  var el =document.createElement('li');
  el.classList.add('ui-state-default');
  el.setAttribute('value',u);
  el.innerHTML=n;
  return el;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given this syntax, the 'this' keyword probably refers to the global 'window' object.  If you are calling the function with the 'new' keyword, the function is being called as a constructor, and you are trying to overwrite the object that it is trying to construct.  Try this istead:

```
function CreateItem(n,u) {
    var li=document.createElement('li');
    li.classList.add('ui-state-default');
    li.setAttribute('value',u);
    li.innerHTML=n;
    return li;
}
```